# Remove a tuple of nan in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe contains a tuple of (lat,lon), but there are some row contain a tuple of nan. How can I remove or detect these?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'location': [1, 2, 3],
                        'coor': [(14.48847, 103.161477),
                              (14.970084, 103.062853),
                              (np.nan, np.nan)]})


    location    coor
0   A   (14.48847, 103.161477)
1   B   (14.970084, 103.062853)
2   C   (nan, nan)
```

I tried.

```
df.isna()

    location    coor
0   False   False
1   False   False
2   False   False

df.dropna()

    location    coor
0   A   (14.48847, 103.161477)
1   B   (14.970084, 103.062853)
2   C   (nan, nan)
```

But it isn't work at all. Should i split a tuple into 2 columns or there is a way to deal with thses? Any help or guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without apply will speed up

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df.coor.tolist()).notna().all(1)]
Out[361]: 
                      coor  location
0   (14.48847, 103.161477)         1
1  (14.970084, 103.062853)         2
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the best answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

you could try filtering using a lambda function

```
df[~df.coor.apply(lambda x: np.isnan(x[0]) & np.isnan(x[1]))]
# prints
   location                     coor
0         1   (14.48847, 103.161477)
1         2  (14.970084, 103.062853)
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually forget  I can use apply to do this.